# Constraining associatedtype of Protocol with another assoicatedtype

Tags: swift, protocols

I've the following 3 protocols.

```
protocol OperationProtocol {
    associatedtype Parameter1
    associatedtype Parameter2
}

protocol Protocol1 {
    associatedtype Type1
}

protocol Protocol2: Protocol1 {
    associatedtype Operation: OperationProtocol
}
```

Now, in Protocol2 declaration, I want to constrain Operation.Parameter1 = Type1

I tried doing a where clause like the following, but I failed.

```
protocol Protocol2: Protocol1 {
    associatedtype Operation: OperationProtocol where Operation.Parameter1 = Self.Type1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to answer it in less than 5 mins after posting the question :)
Here is the answer:

```
protocol Protocol2: Protocol1 {
    associatedtype Operation: OperationProtocol
    associatedtype Type1 = Operation.Parameter1
}
```